# Replace menu item with icon (Prestashop theme)

Tags: icons, prestashop, font-awesome, menubar

I'd like to ask you about the way to replace the text with icon (home icon as the first menu child).

My css is similar to this one:
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/prestashop_53577/

I've added this code at the end of the global.css:

```
.sf-menu li:first-child a:before{
  content: "\f015";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 33px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: black;
}

.sf-menu li ul li a:before{
  content:none!important;
}
```

which gives:

[image]

What's the best way to hide the text "Clothing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add

```
text-indent: -9999em
```

to .sf-menu li:first-child, to indent the text out of view a and then

```
text-indent: 0
```

to .sf-menu li:first-child a:before, to reset the property for the pseudo selector

Comment: thank you. Could you provide some valuable tip how to ignore text-width and hover? I mean keeping the icon in the fixed position. Then should I add the same css for every @media?

Comment: you will need to add  `width: auto;left: 0;` to .sf-menu li:first-child a:before. For the other @media, it depends on what you want visually.

Comment: Thank you but when the the text has a greater width it looks like: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vcx5bo.jpg My point is to ignore top and down bar and just stay it fixed. I'd like to keep the icon for all devices because now it's just blank space.

Comment: What do you mean "when the text has a greater width" ? Do you mean "Clothing" ? If you put `width: auto` it shouldn't be a problem.
As for the others devices, simply put  `position: absolute;` in .sf-menu li:first-child a:before

Comment: I meant something like "Main Page" - more than 1 word. How to ignore hover in the attached image?

Comment: Indeed with several words, there is a problem: add `white-space: nowrap;`  to .sf-menu li:first-child a. 
And what about the hover? I don't understand your question

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. About the hover... There's no point (imho) in moving the icon like this: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vcx5bo.jpg Regardless of the mouse position, I would like to keep it fixed and disable the orange bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82583/discussion-between-devsymediane-and-belford).