# Replace menu item with icon (Media Queries - PrestaShop theme)

Tags: themes, media-queries, prestashop, font-awesome

I've already received some valuable informations in answer related to my previous question but I still have the problem with media queries.
Previous question:
[Replace menu item with icon (Prestashop theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263267/replace-menu-item-with-icon-prestashop-theme)
I'm working with this demo:
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/prestashop_53577

[image]

**The problem is connected with the look on mobile devices. Home icon is hidden. How to make similar effect on max-width: 767 px etc.? Classes are not the same in superfish-modified.css and I'm a little bit confused with that.**

[image]
CSS Files which were changed:

blocktopmenu.css http://pastebin.com/PzyhH9x6
This code was added:

```
.stickUpTop.isStuck .sf-menu li:first-child a:before {
  content: "\f015";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 33px;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: black;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.stickUpTop.isStuck .sf-menu li ul li a:before {
  content: none!important;
}
.stickUpTop.isStuck .sf-menu li:first-child a:after{
  width: 0;
}
```

superfish-modified.css:
http://pastebin.com/f2JG4hnT
This code was added:

```
.sf-menu li:first-child a { 
text-indent: -9999em; 
white-space: nowrap; 
} 

.sf-menu li:first-child a:before{ 
content: "\f015"; 
font-family: "FontAwesome"; 
display: inline-block; 
font-size: 33px; 
line-height: 70px; 
color: black; 
text-indent: 0; 
width: auto; 
left: 0; 
} 

.sf-menu li ul li a:before{ 
content:none!important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this:

```
.sf-menu li:first-child a:before {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and remove on line 92 of superfished-modified.css the line

```
content: "";
```

because that is what remove you icon on smaller resolutions

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to prevent text-indent for child elements. Here you can find what's the problem: http://oi62.tinypic.com/21ayfj8.jpg Is it good idea to write something like .sf-menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(n) a{
  text-indent: 0;
} ?

Comment: Yes or you could target more precisely the parent one by adding ">", `.sf-menu > li:first-child > a`